# How to query an item by a relation

Tags: angular, strapi

In Strapi, I have products that have relationships to topics and industries.

I want to query a product by a related topic using Angular, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how that can be done via the REST API.

i.e: Get all products with the topic "Health".

Any idea?

Documentation isn't clear on how to achieve this.

Below are 2 screenshots of the Topics and Content (products) model. As you can see, they are related many-to-many.

[Topics model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKTQR.png)

[Product model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SKvS.png)

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshots of Product and the relation collections? Also how have you tried to fetch the data currently?

Comment: I've added screenshots. I'm able to get topics and populate the products related to it, and vice versa, but doing that does not allow me to paginate the populated entries.

So knowing a topic ID, I want to get all products that are related.

I'm testing our custom routes/controllers/services in Strapi, but the documentation is really poor and I'm running into issues that are simple not documented.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is no native way to do it using the REST API without creating a route and a controller and/or service to do your query.

Here is my solution for those interested:

In one of my category (in this case industries), I created a custom route that calls a custom controller.

```js
import { factories } from '@strapi/strapi';

export default factories.createCoreRouter('api::industry.industry');

module.exports = {
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/industries/products/:industrySlug',
      handler: 'industry.getRelatedProducts',
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
import { factories } from '@strapi/strapi'

export default factories.createCoreController('api::industry.industry', ({ strapi }) => ({
  async getRelatedProducts(ctx) {
    const {
      offset,
      limit,
    } = ctx.query.pagination;

    const [entries, count] = await strapi.db.query('api::content.content')
      .findWithCount({
        offset,
        limit,
        where: {
          industries: {
            slug: ctx.params.industrySlug,
          }
        },
        orderBy: {
          title: 'asc',
        },
      });

    const data = [];

    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      data.push({
        id: entry.id,
        attributes: {
          ...entry,
        }
      });
    });

    return {
      data,
      meta: {
        pagination: {
          offset: +offset,
          limit: +limit,
          total: count,
        },
      },
    };
  }
}));
```

What sucks with this approach is that there does not seem to be a native way to construct a request payload with the same structure as what the regular API returns. So you have to do it yourself (that includes the pagination).

So by calling the API using the new route `http://localhost:8000/api/industries/products/educational-services?pagination[offset]=24&pagination[limit]=12` I am able to get my products that contain the related `educational-services` industry.